# Can deuterium be formed by gamma rays?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was thinking whether gamma rays could form deuterium by this reaction where gamma rays are really common.

$$p^+ +\gamma(1.98\ Mev)\rightarrow n^0 + e^+ + \ \nu_e$$

$$p^+ +n^0\rightarrow d + 2.2\ Mev$$

Is this possible?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/507613/proton-to-neutron-conversion suggests that your first process is unlikely. As for the second, yes, that process is possible and the data at ENDF will supply you with the cross sections.

Comment: What if I include the energy to turn the proton into a neutron and also supply the energy for the positron and electron neutrino? What would happen then?

Comment: Well, then you have to get them all together in just the right place and you will still have cross sections to worry about... Easier to just get neutrons in the first place.

Comment: What if the entire place was filled with gamma rays and protons this would be possible theoretically right. Then a container that was able to hold all of the things for the reaction inside.